# Mock4as vs Mockito-flex

Tags: actionscript-3, unit-testing, mocking, flexunit4

I'm a bit new to actionscript, but  find myself investigating good programming practices from other OO languages (java/C#) into an actionscript environment. I've given Mock4as and mockito-flex a purusal and was interested in using both.

Has anyone had good/bad experiences using either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had excellent experience with Mockito-flex for the past couple years.  The primary reason I enjoy Mockito-flex over Mocholate is that Mockito lets you test your code using the actual class signatures, thus refactor tools will update your Tests.

Mocholate on the other hand requires that you hardcode the method names with a string, which means no auto-complete help when your creating your tests, and poorer refactoring support if any if you rename and API.

While less important, Mockito is available for multiple languages.  This means that you can use the same mocking syntax in your entire tech stack.  Or you can more easily transfer you mocking skills to another language.

Answer (score 3):

I started out mocking for FlexUnit with mock4as, and it does its job. But it made me spend way too much time writing boilerplate code for my taste.  I haven't tried mockito-flex, but I'll check it out - the Java version I really like.

Recently, I've been really happy with [mockolate](http://mockolate.org/).  Drew Bourne does a really nice job with that - give it a try!